# What is the best way to drive a small coil digitally?

Tags: arduino, led, driver, coil

I have a coil of wire with about 40 mΩ worth of resistance for a hobby project. I would like to put up to 2 A through it. Ideally I would like to be able to choose how much current goes through it in 10 mA increments.

The best idea I had was to use the analog output of an Arduino to control an MP2410. I am trying to minimize noise in the system, so this should work as the [MP2410](https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/documentview/productdocument/index/version/2/document_type/Datasheet/lang/en/sku/MP2410/) does not dim off of PWM.

Any reason this wouldn't work? Any better ways to do voltage controlled current at this scale? MP2410s also seem to be out of stock in most places, so I would be relying on Alibaba.

Comment: If using a voltage to drive it, I would connect a larger resistance up to it to make things easier. The larger that resistacce relative to 40mOhm the more it combined with the voltage source will approximate a current source for low resistances like the 40mOhm.

Comment: Your requirements are not quite clear to me. You seem to need an adjustable current source to drive a coil while minimizing noise. Some more Insight on the application might lead to better answers. MP2410 is a switching regulator and does not provide a low noise current.

Comment: You cannot instantly increment the current in a coil. You can do that with voltage but not current. If you try to step-change current you'll get a back-emf that might destroy your electronics.

Comment: Do you know the coil's inductance? If it's high enough, you can use the coil as **part of** the constant-current driver, which is convenient.

Comment: You can use a lab or other power supply that has current limit. Be sure the voltage available will give you the end result you want. Then adjust the current for each step, very easy to do with a Lab power supply and if you have a bunch using a programmable supply will make it even easier. If it is just one this would be a good excuse to get that lab supply you want, they can be gotten for less then $50.00.

Comment: so you want to put up-to, 160mW of power into the coil.  at 5V that would be 32mA,  is there any chance you can re-do the coil to have more turns?

Comment: Is this part of a solution or just for a single evaluation sequence to test something?

Comment: DKNguyen I was thinking about attaching a resistor to it to artificially increase the resistance. Not entirely sure how to pick the right size though.


LarsHankeln I thought since MP2410 wasn't PWM that it wouldnt be switching. Am I missing something?

Andyaka It doesnt have to be instant step ranging, I just meant that I wanted to have fine control over the current.

user253751 the inductance isn't too high, its like 4 meters of gauge 16 cable.

Comment: Gil I understand a lab power supply, or a buck converter would work, but I would like to have digital control over the system. Basically I would like to put a magnetometer in the loop and let the system change the current until the magnetic field is optimized.

Jasen The coil has as many turns as I can fit in my system.

Jens This is part of a solution.